# use parameter as date in execute script

Tags: sql, variables, groovy, apache-nifi

I am working on execute Script processor in nifi.  I declared `lastdate`
as `2020-12-21` and I am trying to use this attribute in execute script
(groovy) file to fetch data from oracle.

In oracle it gave me the correct result. In nifi go to failure.

My code (script body):

```
def last_data = flowFile.getAttribute('last_date')

query = "select t.* from mytable where r.mydate > " + last_date + ",'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Comment: `select t.* from mytable where r.mydate > 2020-12-21 ,'yyyy-mm-dd')` is not a correct query

Comment: What failure? Please add the error message, log-entry, stacktrace, ...

Answer (score 0):

Hehe, your variable is last_datA and you concatene last_datE.

I thinks that it buddy :)

Comment: def last_date* :)

Comment: @Keedy Please edit the question if there are typos in it.

Comment: my problem is that i want to load a query in execute scipt in nifi and the where condition of this query is related to the last queue attribute.